# convert to PDF from html or svg, which one is best?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, svg

I am going to work on some project where i need to create PDF of some sections in webpage...

Its completely in decision phase what should do for it...

So i have found that we can convert HTML to PDF using some js OR other lib which work at server end...same i found for SVG images...

But confusion is like some time info found as HTML to PDF is good idea whereas few says SVG to PDF will be good for you to maintain Quality etc...

So I wan views with experience that which is best way to go with?

Comment: ***primarily opinion-based** Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* - You have a high enough experience with SO by now that you should know this. Therefor I'm vote-closing this question.

Comment: i don't want opinion or vote of somebody. I am looking for experience guideline to go with from someone who worked with both ways... or gone through such case where he understand things correctly...If its opinion base then for sure one worked for HTML will vote for html and svg guys for SVG to pdf thats it but its related to technical view don't just look as vote...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a PDF of a webpage then you'll have to convert from HTML to PDF.  You cannot convert from SVG to PDF because simply you don't have the SVG - which is a vectorial image format - to start with.  Then the question is not whichever it's the best, it's which is the most appropriate for your use case.

Note that HTML describes the structure of a document, not its style (this can be done via CSS) and hence not the way it appears.